# Early Access: Dynamically expanding input element table

Tags: javascript, beginner, form, dom

This code is in a really early state in the lifecycle. I'm still in the process of implementing some core features, but nevertheless the code up to here works and accomplishes its task.

I have no idea as to how well, though.

This code is intended to give a dead-simple way of creating growable and shrinkable form content for things like: multiple addresses, multiple courses, multiple X.

As such, it is intended (but not yet able) to fully support all kinds of form elements, including radio buttons and dropdowns.

The goal is providing a single registration once on page-load and then automatize generation of input-names from a template, generation of new form fields for new "rows", removal of rows as well as providing a way to simplistically style the form-fields.

To stay lightweight I decided to implement this in vanilla-js. The current state of the code can be found at [this revision](https://github.com/Vogel612/DynamicForm/tree/0f990f9ae01470713283342c870df195c1b5f662) in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Vogel612/DynamicForm)

I am aware and intend to timely "fix" following shortcomings:

- Lack of documentation
- Constraint to table-structure in html
- Lacking support for all types of inputs currently supported are only the inputs that have the tagname `input`
- Actual numbering of inputs by row through the nametemplate

These "features" are currently marked with `FIXME` comments.

```js
// FIXME jsdoc
function DynamicForm(parent, coreConfig, formOptions) {
  // require input data from formOptions
  if (formOptions === undefined || formOptions.inputs === undefined) {
    console.warn("Cannot create a DynamicForm without formOptions");
    return false;
  }
  if (parent === undefined) {
    console.warn("Cannot create a DynamicForm without a structure to bind to");
    return false;
  }

  var add_icon;
  if (coreConfig.add_icon === undefined) {
    add_icon =
      'data:image/png;base64,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';
  } else {
    add_icon = coreConfig.add_icon;
  }
  var remove_icon;
  if (coreConfig.remove_icon === undefined) {
    remove_icon =
      'data:image/png;base64,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';
  } else {
    remove_icon = coreConfig.remove_icon;
  }
  // FIXME: add a way to use nested divs
  var tbody = parent.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var inputOpts = formOptions.inputs;

  var self = {
    add: function () {
      var newRow = tbody.insertRow(-1);
      addInputs(newRow);
      organizeForm();
    }
    , remove: function (node) {
      if (tbody.children.length == 1) {
        return false;
      }
      tbody.removeChild(node);
      organizeForm();
      return true;
    }
  };

  // run that for each field actually..
  var addInputs = function (tableRow) {
    // iterate over configurated inputs
    for (
      var config of inputOpts) {
      var cell = tableRow.insertCell(-1);
      // FIXME: correct the behaviour..
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.type = config.type;
      input.className = config.classname === undefined ? coreConfig.defaultClass :
        config.className;
      input.name = config.nametemplate;

      cell.appendChild(input);
    }
  };

  var organizeForm = function () {
    var rows = tbody.children;
    for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
      while (rows[r].childElementCount > inputOpts.length) {
        rows[r].deleteCell(inputOpts.length);
      }
      var cell = rows[r].insertCell(-1);
      var remove = new Image();
      remove.src = remove_icon;
      remove.onclick = function () {
        self.remove(this.parentElement.parentElement); // remove row on click!
      }
      cell.appendChild(remove);
      // last row!
      if (r == rows.length - 1) {
        var add = new Image();
        add.src = add_icon;
        add.onclick = function () {
          self.add();
        }
        cell.appendChild(add);
      }
      // FIXME correct this behaviour
      // var txt = rows[r].children[1].children[0];
      // txt.name = inputOpts.nametemplate.replace(/%INDEX%/, r);
    }
  };
  organizeForm();
  return self;
}
```

```css
        img {
          margin: 5px;
        }
        .df-input {
          padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var df = DynamicForm(document.getElementById('df-parent-0'), {
          defaultClass : 'df-input'
        }, {
          inputs: [
            {type : 'text', nametemplate : 'textfield'}
            , {type : 'checkbox', nametemplate : 'checkbox'}
          ]
        });
        df.add();
      };
    </script>
    This is some random content :D
    <form action="#" name="example">
      <table id="df-parent-0">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added some skeleton HTML and CSS to demonstrate that the code can currently do the following:

- Add rows to a table according to a simplistic configuration
- Remove rows from a table

Yes, it is intended that the minus sign does not do anything if there is only one row left.

Please note that the code is also licensed under the MIT License.

#### Concerns

I am concerned about:

- Proper use of DOM manipulation
- Idiomaticness of creating a DynamicForm

Note that I'm still getting into the guts of atom to make the automatic formatting work as I want it to, so comments on what needs cleanup there are much appreciated.

Comment: For whatever reason it seems I cannot bind a listener to window.onload.... if there's someone that can fix the code-snippet in that respect, that would be absolutely awesome

Comment: I think I got your snippet working. The `visible: false` flags for the HTML and CSS did hide those blocks, but also caused them to be completely ignored by the snippet system (couldn't "copy to answer" either). So the snippet was _only_ loading your JS, but no content. I tried a similar thing once, but it seems it's all or nothing with snippets; can't hide/show individual parts.

Comment: I'm wondering; if the minus-button can't remove the last row, that implies you'll always want at least 1 row. If so, it would let you put that 1st row directly in the HTML and use it as a template for the following ones. Would that be an option?

Comment: while that would definitely be an option I am not sure I want to constrain myself to that behaviour. Especially when I want this to also work for nested div-structures that emulate tables... then again that might just be wishful thinking. That definitely sounds like an idea worth exploring :) Also the "minimum 1 row" thing is actually a crutch to always have a plus there, that doesn't want to be all alone :D

Comment: True, it's a different approach. Yet it could also allow for more complex HTML. Anyway, I've been meaning to answer this question, just haven't had the time yet. Will get to it (and perhaps propose an alternative solution)

Comment: Dang, I said I get to this, and I still haven't. Got a large project dumped in my lap at work, and had to do some travelling. I will try to find the time this weekend though, but no guarantees, I'm afraid

Comment: Hey @Flambino I though you might be intersted, so I'm notifying you via comment: Bounty runs out in 7 hours :)

Comment: Oh dear. Yeah, I'm terrible at keeping my word here. So sorry. I've been flying (literally and figuratively) to and fro for the past week and half. Thanks for the ping (and good thing I got it on my phone or I never would've seen it) but I'm not gonna make the bounty deadline :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `console.warn`:

> ```
>   if (formOptions === undefined || formOptions.inputs === undefined) {
>     console.warn("Cannot create a DynamicForm without formOptions");
>     return false;
>   }
>   if (parent === undefined) {
>     console.warn("Cannot create a DynamicForm without a structure to bind to");
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

Instead of using `console.warn` with a `return`, use `throw new Error` instead:

It kills the function entirely and provides a stack trace.

---

### Big base64 strings:

I would store those big strings as constants at the top of the function as to improve readability, adding `b64_` to the beginning: `b64_add_icon`

Then, you can use ternaries instead of the `if` statements:

```
var add_icon = coreConfig.add_icon === undefined ? b64_add_icon : coreConfig.add_icon;
```

---

### `snake_case`:

You shouldn't be using `snake_case` in JavaScript, you should be using `camelCase`.

---

### `var self = {`:

You shouldn't work it like that, just assign `self` as an empty object, and then work from there, or use the prototype chain.

---

### `for`:

I'm not sure why the content of the `for` loop is on a different line, perhaps design influence from another language?

> ```
> for (
>   var config of inputOpts) {
> ```

also in another `for` loop, you can declare the `length` in the loop to save constant calls to the `length` property:

```
for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
```

into:

```
for (var r = 0, length = rows.length; r < length; r++) {
```

---

### `onclick`:

Instead of `onclick`, you should use `addEventListener("click", ...`

```
  remove.onclick = function () {
    self.remove(this.parentElement.parentElement); // remove row on click!
  }
```

into:

```
  remove.addEventListener('click', function () {
    self.remove(this.parentElement.parentElement); // remove row on click!
  });
```

---

### Truthy and Falsy checks:

Be careful when using the `==` and `!=` operators as they can falsely compare values, see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) for more information.

> ```
> if (r == rows.length - 1) {
> ```

---

### Misc:

- `document.createElement("INPUT")`: html tags aren't uppercase, and neither does the parameter string need to be.
- Ternary improvement; I like to structure my ternaries the following way for maximum prettiness:

> ```
>   input.className = config.classname === undefined ? coreConfig.defaultClass :
>     config.className;
> ```

into:

```
  input.className = config.classname === undefined
                        ? coreConfig.defaultClass
                        : config.className;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't create unnecessary `if-else` block to check for `add_icon` and `remove_icon` respectively.

   ```
   var add_icon = coreConfig.add_icon || 'data:...BV58AAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
   ```

   would work just as well.
2. I'd favour usage of `tbody.rows` over `tbody.children`.
3. Try to have all your functions `return` something, just to be consistent.

   ```
   var self = {
       add: function () {
         var newRow = tbody.insertRow(-1);
         addInputs(newRow);
         return organizeForm();
       },
       remove: function (node) {
         if (tbody.children.length == 1) {
           return false;
         }
         tbody.removeChild(node);
         return organizeForm();
       }
   };
   ```

   and just put a `return true` in the `organizeForm` declaration. I am unaware whether JavaScript happens to have [tail calls](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html) or not!
4. Let the users' use actual attribute names when providing `inputOpts`. This will not confuse the new users, and they can always reference W3C definitions to see which attributes they can use. So, instead of `classname` and `nametemplate`; let there be `className` and `name` respectively.

   With the above in place, you won't need to individually assign the properties. This can be done with a simple deep-copy of properties across objects.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the Goal of the nametemplate. The nametemplate is intended to allow the user to configure a Name, that changes depending on what row the Input has. That functionality is not quite finished yet though, since I wanted to get a very early Review. But all the other Points you make are very interesting and I think I will get all of them into the code. Thank you :)